# Make div scrollable and show pseudo-element

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I have a very long currency div and I'd like to make it scrollable.

In order to achieve that, I set on the div the css properties:

```
overflow-y: auto;
height: 200px;
```

That worked and made the div scrollable but I have a problem: the little arrow-up you can see in the picture is placed on the pseudo-element `::before` and set `overflow-y: auto;` on the main div make it disappear.

How can I make the div scrollable and show the pseudo-element `::before`?

[image]

[image]

Here's the actual HTML:

```
<div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options active">
::before
            <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger active" id="switcher-currency-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger-keypress-button="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0">
                <strong class="language-EUR">
                    <span>EUR - Euro</span>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown" aria-hidden="false">
::before
                                                            <li class="currency-ALL switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">ALL - Albanian Lek</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-ARS switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">ARS - Argentine Peso</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-AUD switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">AUD - Australian Dollar</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-BYN switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">BYN - Belarusian Ruble</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-BZD switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">BZD - Belize Dollar</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-BAM switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">BAM - Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-BRL switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">BRL - Brazilian Real</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-GBP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">GBP - British Pound</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-BGN switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">BGN - Bulgarian Lev</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CAD switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CAD - Canadian Dollar</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CLP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CLP - Chilean Peso</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CNY switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CNY - Chinese Yuan</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-COP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">COP - Colombian Peso</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CRC switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CRC - Costa Rican Colón</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-HRK switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">HRK - Croatian Kuna</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CUP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CUP - Cuban Peso</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-CZK switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">CZK - Czech Koruna</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-DKK switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">DKK - Danish Krone</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-DOP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">DOP - Dominican Peso</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-EGP switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">EGP - Egyptian Pound</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                                                    <li class="currency-HKD switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">HKD - Hong Kong Dollar</a>
                        </li>
                                                                                <li class="currency-HUF switcher-option">
                            <a href="#">HUF - Hungarian Forint</a>
                        </li>
                                                </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `::before` element to the parent of the `div` with the fixed height (if it has any).

If that is not an option, can you add a wrapper to your `ul` element?

Then you can add the `::before` to the parent element. Something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/84g2acxk/10/).

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I cannot move the ::before element to the parent since this latter has already its own ::before pseudo-element. I updated the question with the actual HTML.

Comment: @KaMZaTa Can you maybe add one more wrapper element to the `ul` then?